# Variable value in http request

Tags: http, lua, request

I have a Variable value in a http request

```
local data = http.request('http://ip:port/json.htm?type=devices&rid=3')
```

The number 3 is a variable value.
How to insert `number` instead off `3`

```
local data = http.request('http://ip:port/json.htm?type=devices&rid=number')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [concatenation operator '**..**'](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.6) :

```
local data = http.request('http://ip:port/json.htm?type=devices&rid=' .. number)
```

Or  [string.format](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.format):

```
local data = http.request(string.format('http://ip:port/json.htm?type=devices&rid=%d', number))
```